# FastColoredTextbox issue scrolling the text and positioning the caret

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, visual-studio

This question is about the extended control: FastColoredTextbox here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/161871/Fast-Colored-TextBox-for-syntax-highlighting

I'm trying to auto scroll down the text and to put the text-cursor in the last character of the appended text (the total length of the text property I suppose).

> Text scrolling problem

This is working for the automatic text scrolling:

```
  Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        FastColoredTextBox1.Text = str
        FastColoredTextBox1.ScrollLeft()
        FastColoredTextBox1.Navigate(FastColoredTextBox1.Lines.Count - 1)
  End Sub
```

...But I want to make it more generic, and this don't work:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    FastColoredTextBox1.Text = str
End Sub


Private Sub FastColoredTextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As FastColoredTextBoxNS.TextChangedEventArgs) Handles FastColoredTextBox1.TextChanged
    sender.ScrollLeft()
    sender.Navigate(FastColoredTextBox1.Lines.Count - 1)
End Sub
```

Any error or exception, just don't will work, the text is not scrolled like in the first example.

> Keyboard cursor position problem

About the text-cursor, I've tried this but don't work too:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    FastColoredTextBox1.Text = str
    FastColoredTextBox1.SelectionStart = FastColoredTextBox1.Text.Length
End Sub
```

Any error or exception, just don't work.

> UPDATE

Tried the @ebyrob solution but does not work, it does not scroll to down.

```
Imports FastColoredTextBoxNS

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim str As String = String.Empty
        For x As Int32 = 1 To 1000 : str += vbNewLine & x : Next
        FastColoredTextBox1.Text = str
    End Sub

    Private Sub FastColoredTextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As TextChangedEventArgs) Handles FastColoredTextBox1.TextChanged
        GoEnd()
    End Sub

    Public Sub GoEnd()
        If FastColoredTextBox1.Lines.Count > 0 Then
            FastColoredTextBox1.Selection.Start = New Place(FastColoredTextBox1.Lines(FastColoredTextBox1.Lines.Count - 1).Count, FastColoredTextBox1.Lines.Count - 1)
        Else
            FastColoredTextBox1.Selection.Start = New Place(0, 0)
        End If
        FastColoredTextBox1.DoCaretVisible()
    End Sub

End Class
```

> Update Two

The @ebyrob code works only if I call "GoEnd" always after appending the text, like this example:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim str As String = String.Empty
    For x As Int32 = 1 To 1000 : str += vbNewLine & x : Next
    FastColoredTextBox1.Text = str
    GoEnd()
End Sub
```

That is the same problem of my first problem that I've commented (TextChanged event is not working as expected), I need to make it efficient and generic, I was supposed the "TextChanged" event of the Control would be the correct event to put the "GoEnd()" but definitivelly is not.

I don't want to make this ever:

```
1. Add text
2. Call GoEnd
3. Add more text
4. Call again GoEnd
```

I wan't to put "GoEnd" in a event which succed when text is changed to simplify the things:

```
1. add text
2. add more text
```

> UPDATE THREE

All the problems are solved, just changed the event name:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim mytext As String = String.Empty
        For x As Int32 = 1 To 1000 : mytext += vbNewLine & x : Next
        FastColoredTextBox1.Text += mytext
        FastColoredTextBox1.Focus()
    End Sub

Private Sub FastColoredTextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As FastColoredTextBoxNS.TextChangedEventArgs) _
    Handles FastColoredTextBox1.TextChangedDelayed

    sender.ScrollLeft()
    sender.Navigate(sender.Lines.Count - 1)
    FastColoredTextBox1.SelectionStart = FastColoredTextBox1.Text.Length

End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what exactly your question is and what you are trying to achieve... can you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"?  Is it simply a compile error due to not casting sender to FastColoredTextBox?  Also shouldn't the last example be `.SelectionStart = FastColoredTextBox1.Text.Length - 1`?

Comment: You are going to have to cast that `sender` object.  You need to document what this FastColoredTextBox component is.

Comment: @LarsTech It seems to be this one: https://github.com/PavelTorgashov/FastColoredTextBox/blob/master/FastColoredTextBox/FastColoredTextBox.cs and it seems `SetCaretPos()` actually manipulates the keyboard cursor.

Comment: @ebyrob I found the same one, presumably, at [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/161871/Fast-Colored-TextBox-for-syntax-highlighting).  The point is though, the OP shouldn't make the community guess at the component that is being questioned.

Comment: I will make some changes in the question in a minute guys, thanks for comment

Comment: @ebyrob by "does not work" I will mean the text is not scrolled and in the second example the caret position don't chnage, but all this without any error/exception.

Comment: @LarsTech there is any public property "setCaretPos" that I can use in the control, or maybe I'm missing something in your comment? sorry I'm a little newbie

Comment: @Everybody Question updated

Comment: Oh and also about the sender object, I've tried it with and without (I mean with the correct control name and using the sender object that contains the control too), the sender is not the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently there is already a method just for this operation:

```
    public void GoEnd()
    {
        if (lines.Count > 0)
            Selection.Start = new Place(lines[lines.Count - 1].Count,
                                        lines.Count - 1);
        else
            Selection.Start = new Place(0, 0);

        DoCaretVisible();
    }
```

Note you'll also want:

```
Dim tbSender as FastColoredTextBox
tbSender = DirectCast(sender, FastColoredTextBox) 
tbSender.Text = str
tbSender.GoEnd()
' ...
```

Finally I recommend:

```
Option Explicit
```

In just about all VB code.

**EDIT: after testing the control, delayed event works**

```
FastColoredTextBox1.TextChangedDelayed += FastColoredTextBox1_TextChanged;
```

Note: This means a default 100 ms delay for each event fired.

Comment: Thanks for comment, I've translated it but does not work (any exception) the text is not scrolled and the text-cursor stills in the first letter of the full text, you can see the code in my updated question (sorry 'cause my english).

Comment: When you call `GoEnd()` above, where is it attached to an object?  Also, are you using `Option Explicit`?  Finally, what happens if you click the button twice in the "generic" solution.  Does it scroll part-way?  If so, then you have a timing problem with the event, it may be firing before the text is actually updated.

Comment: No matter finally I did it trying all the events one by one, I was sure the problem would be the event and yes, the correct event is ".TextChangedDelayed", I don't need a large procedure as "goend" 'cause the control have their methods to make this but thanks for your time!